# Average Distance of Fully Connected Graph with Tail

Tags: graph-theory

I have a graph that is fully connected with $n$ nodes and it has  a tail of length $c$ attached:

[image]

In this example, n = 4 and c = 3.

In general, the diameter of this graph is $1+c$ (traverse from the end of the tail to one of the nodes in the fully connected component).

Is it possible to come up with an expression for the average distance (=average distance over all pairs of nodes in the graph) for this graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $K_n$ be your fully connected part with vertex set $v_1,\ldots,v_n$. Let $P=(w_c,w_{c-1},\ldots,w_1)$ be your tail where $w_1$ is connected to $v_1$ by a single edge.

Denote the distance between vertices $a$ and $b$ by $d(a,b)$.

*Case 1*: $a=v_i$ and $b=v_j$ for some $i\neq j$. Then $d(v_i,v_j)=1$ so $$\sum_{i,j,i\neq j} d(v_i,v_j) =\sum_{i,j,i\neq j} 1 ={n\choose 2}.$$

*Case 2*: $a=w_i$ and $b=v_1$: Then $d(a,b)=i$ so $$\sum_{i=1}^c d(w_i,v_1) = 1+2+\cdots c = {c+1\choose 2}.$$

*Case 3*: $a=w_i$ and $b=v_j$ for $j\neq 1$. Then $d(a,b)=i+1$. Thus $$\sum_{j=2}^n\sum_{i=1}^c d(w_i,v_j) = \sum_{j=2}^n\sum_{i=1}^c i+1 = (n-1)\left({c+1\choose 2}+c\right).$$

*Case 4*: $a=w_i$ and $b=w_j$ for some $i<j$. Then $d(a,b)=j-i$. So $$\sum_{j=1}^c\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} d(w_j,w_i) = \sum_{j=1}^c\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} j-i = {c+1\choose 3}. $$

Putting it all together we see that the average distance is

$$\frac{{n\choose 2}+n{c+1\choose 2}+c(n-1)+{c+1\choose 3}}{{n+c\choose 2}}.$$